# Restrict Google Autocomplete results using bounds option

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am trying to use Google Places Autocomplete and restrict the results to a specific city in Canada, namely Toronto.  I am aware that using the `componentRestrictions` option will allow me to restrict the results to Canada by using `componentRestrictions: {country: 'CA'}`.  In order to further restrict the results to Toronto, I understand that I have to add the `bounds` property to the `options` object.  The `LatLngBounds` expects south-west and north-east corners, which are also referred to as bottom-left and top-right corners.

I found this sample code which implements this strategy for the City of Hyderabad in Pakistan and it works perfectly:

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng( 25.341233, 68.289986 );
var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng( 25.450715, 68.428345 );
var HyderabadBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds( southWest, northEast );

var options = {
    bounds: HyderabadBounds,
    types:  ['address'],
    componentRestrictions: { country: 'PK' }
};

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete( input, options);
```

When I try to modify the code to work for an area in Canada, for some reason it is not working.  Here is my modified code:

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng( 43.941160, -78.895187 );
var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng( 42.946172, -81.296577 );
var TorontoBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds( southWest, northEast );

var options = {
    bounds: TorontoBounds,
    types:  ['address'],
    componentRestrictions: { country: 'CA' }
};

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete( input, options);
```

The only thing different about my modified code is the country designation `CA` and the LatLng coordinates which I believe to be correct.  I double-checked my coordinates and the southWest coordinate refers to a location southWest of Toronto and the northEast coordinate refers to a location northEast of Toronto, so I would expect that these should work.  Although my results are properly restricted to Canada, they are not within my bounds as specified by the LatLng coordinates.

Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: see my answer here, hope it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62294304/4324194

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `northEast` and `southWest` points are named incorrectly.  Change their names:

```
var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng(43.941160, -78.895187);
var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng(42.946172, -81.296577);
```

[image: screenshot of southWest and northEast locations]

If I set them to:

```
var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng(43.941160, -78.895187);
var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng(42.946172, -81.296577);
```

The bounds object is correct.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/o0d9a4pf/2/)

[image: screenshot with correct northEast/southWest naming]

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -33.8688,
      lng: 151.2195
    },
    zoom: 13
  });
  var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
  var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng(43.941160, -78.895187);
  var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng(42.946172, -81.296577);

  var SWmark = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: southWest,
    title: southWest.toUrlValue(6),
    label: "SW"
  });
  var NEmark = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: northEast,
    title: northEast.toUrlValue(6),
    label: "NE"
  });
  var TorontoBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
  var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    map: map,
    bounds: TorontoBounds
  });
  map.fitBounds(TorontoBounds);
  var options = {
    bounds: TorontoBounds,
    types: ['address'],
    componentRestrictions: {
      country: 'CA'
    }
  };

  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 80%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="pac-container">
  <input id="searchTextField" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="infowindow-content">
  <img src="" width="16" height="16" id="place-icon">
  <span id="place-name" class="title"></span><br>
  <span id="place-address"></span>
</div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```