# Google Geocode Autocomplete restrict to Maryland State

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-geocoder

I am trying to restrict the Google Autocomplete results to a particular state, using Cornad's answer here - [Google GeoCode Autocomplete limit State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871190/google-geocode-autocomplete-limit-state/49641192#49641192). Its working for California(ca) where as not working with Maryland co-ordinates. Can any one please take a look and help. Full code here- https://jsfiddle.net/zuhpwjcq/ and below are the working and not working snippets

Working code -

```
var stateBounds={
        ca: ["32.812736", "-119.216815", "34.608128", "-117.039301"]
        // lat/long boundaries list for states/provinces.
    };

    function getStateBounds(state) {
        return new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
          new google.maps.LatLng(stateBounds[state][0], 
                                 stateBounds[state][1]), 
          new google.maps.LatLng(stateBounds[state][2], 
                                 stateBounds[state][3])
        ); 
    }

    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('search'), {
        types: ['address'],
        componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'},
        bounds: getStateBounds('ca') // get LatLngBounds for ca.
    });
```

Not working code -

```
var stateBounds={
        md: ["39.0457549", "76.64127119999999"]
        // lat/long boundaries list for states/provinces.
    };

    function getStateBounds(state) {
        return new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
          new google.maps.LatLng(stateBounds[state][0], 
                                 stateBounds[state][1])
        ); 
    }

    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('search'), {
        types: ['address'],
        componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'},
        bounds: getStateBounds('md') // get LatLngBounds for ca.
    });
```

Comment: A bounds is a square defined by two corners.  You only have a single point.

Comment: Yes , I just realised it and started using location and radius instead but the results are not accurate. Will you be able to help please

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.  Restricting the auto complete to a square is not likely to exactly correspond to the actual (polygon) shape of the state (particularly for a state shaped like Maryland)

Comment: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/q20La5bt/4/) visualising the bounds (black box) vs the border (red polygon) of the state of Maryland.

Comment: @geocodezip I was able to restrict to only Maryland state using "location" as bounds is not apt as per your explanation. Here is the code that worked 

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.0457549,-76.64127119999999);
service.getPlacePredictions({
            input: value,
            types: type,
            componentRestrictions: {
              country: 'us'
            },
            location: myLatlng,
            radius: 500,
            strictBounds: true
          }

Comment: Now, as the LatLang is for Maryland, I got a change in requirement to restrict only to two cities in Maryland. @geocodezip Do you know how we can add two lat lang to location parameter. Or is there a way where we can use a range of lat lang that covers these two cities in Maryland - Anne Arrundel and Prince George

Comment: The bounds of a circle is a square that still will return results outside of the state/city.  The change you made that effected the results was adding `strictbounds: true`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216978/discussion-between-an-user-and-geocodezip).

Answer (score -1):

I was able to restrict to only Maryland state using "location" as bounds is not apt as per @geocodezip's explanation. Here is the code that worked

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.0457549,-76.64127119999999); service.getPlacePredictions({
            input: value,
            types: type,
            componentRestrictions: {
              country: 'us'
            },
            location: myLatlng,
            radius: 500,
            strictBounds: true
          }
```

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer to your own question. You asked how to restrict the Autocomplete to the state of Maryland. This instead, will restrict the Autocomplete to a given location and a radius of 500 meters.